# How to download data to NSOutputStream via AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I use AFNetworking 2.x to download zip  archives to files. I've implemented it through settings NSOutputStream to a AFURLConnectionOperation property.
How I can implement similar possibility in the 3.x version of AFNetworking library?

**UPD**
I have inner library, which uses NSOutputStream to downloads big files and stores theirs to a disk without store complete data to the memory.
Also NSOutputStream lets make universal writer, which can write to any destination. NSOutputStream decides how he will write to the destination.
Therefore I want use NSOutputStream with the 3.x, and now I'm finding the shortest path to implement it.

Comment: Do you want to know how to download and save a file to a location on disk?

Comment: No, I want to know how to use NSOutputStream with AFNetworking 3.0.